# How to create multi pages pdf in flutter with images?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of file image paths. I need to create pdf from these images. How can I do it? I already know how to create pdf from a single image using pdf package.

Answer (score 2):

Replace Page widget with MultiPage widget, default max pages is 20.

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

final pdf = Document();
  pdf.addPage(
    MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (Context context) => <Widget>[*/your widgets here*/],
    )
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) library. The documentation contains example codes which will let you create a pdf file with multiple pages with images inside.

```dart
final image = PdfImage.file(
  pdf.document,
  bytes: File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync(),
);

final pdf = pw.Document();

final image = PdfImage.file(
  pdf.document,
  bytes: File('test.webp').readAsBytesSync(),
);

pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Image(image),
      ); // Center
    })); // Page

final file = File("example.pdf");
await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
```